# iOS - When to load JSON data

Tags: ios, json, xcode, appdelegate

I know this may sound general but wanted to get feedback/opinions on when or where to parse and store all the JSON data you will need for your view controllers.

I want to use the AppDelegate didFinishLoadingWithOptions to instantiate a parent class that would grab the JSON data and store it in that class and then when you need to access to the data or subsets of the data for a specific view controller(ask for it in viewWillAppear) you can call a class method of that parent class(or whatever) to return to you the data that you need

The opposite design of this would be to let each VC have a specific JSON call to get its specific data instead of calling a class method on the parent class mentioned above to return the data it needs but this seems clunky and unintuitive as well as it breaks the MVC design. (The VC shouldn't really be concerned with JSON or parsing JSON at all).
 - I have done it this way but it was one VC and for discovery/learning purposes only.

Just wanted to get feedback and perhaps confirm that the first design is the best.

Comment: That doesn't make sense: "I want to use the AppDelegate didFinishLoadingWithOptions to instantiate a parent class that would grab the JSON data "

Comment: do you have multiple json files? can't you try to store them in CoreData?

Comment: its just one http link but i will need different specific links to get to more of the data that i need. The data will always been changing behind the scenes so parsing the json data will need to be frequent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question for programmers.stackexchange.com.

But I think the best wisdom is neither. Create an independent data model, and have it control loading and saving data.

The data model will have methods which will allow view controllers to get the data they need. You might wish to have `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` instantiate the data model (not the best practice).

The important thing is have data model handle the work of preserving state, that way loading and storing data is more flexible.

Comment: when you say, "independent data model" you are talking about core data ? I will be parsing JIRA (which is just rest) so you have the projects (parent) then each project has an ID, the issues, the lead etc etc and I was thinking of having a class for each of those to build up a model with. BUT it might be easier to use NSFetchedResultsController for the updating  -  maybe thats where you were going?

Comment: Also remember that the JSON data will be changing all the time so i need to find the best way to update the app (and the vc's in the app) as the changes come in and not necessarily every time the app starts.

Comment: @cspam It doesn't have to be core data, just a separate set of classes to hold the data and business logic.

Comment: @cspam as for the data changing, this is why you need the abstraction of a data model. It's the data model's responsibility to maintain state. This prevents you from having to synchronize that work between all the view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one set of data common to all VCs, have ONE central 'Store class' -- you can init that whenever you want and pass it between VCs (or rather... use it from the VC)

```
//very much simplified
@interface Store
+ (id)sharedStore
- (id)getJSONForMe
@end
```

...

```
//in a viewController, use the Store
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    id myjson = [[Store sharedStore] getJSONForMe];
}
```